# How to hide keyboard suggestion view in keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

How to hide keyboard suggestion view in keyboard?

I Tried following methods  but they don't working.

`amountTextField.textContentType = UITextContentType(rawValue: "")` and `amountTextField.autocorrectionType = .no`[image]

Comment: When I get OTP I go to the next page, where I want to hide keyboard suggestion view

Comment: are you tried amountTextField.textContentType = UITextContentType( "")

Comment: I had tried it, but it don't working